# getline problems in c++

Tags: c++, getline

What is wrong with this code the text is very simple its just a simple text file like this

```
1
2345
5673
```

I'm just trying to get the first element of the text.

***Here is my code snippet:***

```
ifstream matchInput("SampleMatchFile.txt");
match match1;
int numLines;
string firstLine;
getline(matchInput, firstLine);`
```

firstLine doesnt have anything in it after getline is called. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: make sure you actually open the correct file

Comment: And also make sure there's no blank line before the 1.

Comment: so there isnt anything wrong with what i wrote because im almost certain is the correct file

Comment: Check that the file opened with `matchInput.is_open()` and check the return from `getline` to see if it failed.

Comment: @nateotoole _"im almost certain is the correct file ..."_ **almost** isn't enough in conjunction with programming. It's an exact science!

Comment: Using a full path name highly improves the odds of finding the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking the valid state of `matchInput` at any point. You rather should write a code like this:

```
ifstream matchInput("SampleMatchFile.txt");
match match1;
youint numLines;
string firstLine;

if(matchInput) {
    if(!getline(matchInput, firstLine)) {
        // indicate error extracting a line
    }
}
else {
    // indicate error opening the file
}
```

Opening files from relative paths depends on the working directory that your program is actually running from. Check your IDE's settings and compare with the path of your intended input file.